# sox: How to specify audio input and audio output devices on OSX

Tags: macos, sox, coreaudio

In Linux, I used to use the following command, which takes audio input, applies reverb and a pitch shift effects, and then outputs the result to the specified audio device.

```
sox -r 44100 -t alsa hw:1 -t alsa hw:0 reverb 1 50 10 50 pitch 100
```

On mac/OSX, I have installed the commandline audio utility `sox`, and I can record OR play audio using `-d` (default audio device), but I'm unable to  get sox to do the same real-time audio manipulation that I did in Linux shown above. I think the key is finding out what to specify for the `-t` option

Comment: I've linked to this in the [Ask Different chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat), with this comment... QA from SU I find fascinating - I've been a Mac audio guy for 30 years & didn't know anything like this existed. I've always used some kind of GUI app/util to do this kind of thing; either ASIO, Soundflower [back in the day] or Rogue Amoeba.

Comment: You learn something new every day ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, the trick was 1. to specify `-t coreaudio` followed by the device name, and 2. figuring out what to use for the device name.

What to use for the device name:

```
$ sox -V6 -n -t coreaudio junkname

<snip>
sox INFO coreaudio: Found Audio Device "Built-in Mi"
sox INFO coreaudio: Found Audio Device "Built-in Ou"
sox INFO coreaudio: Found Audio Device "Scarlett 2i"
```

Full commandline:

```
sox -r 48000 -t coreaudio "Scarlett 2i2 USB" -t coreaudio "Built-in Output" reverb 1 50 10 50 pitch 100
```

I was able to run the command successfully with either the abbreviated names shown in the -V6 output, as well as the full name seen in sound settings under system preferences.

OS: Mojave/10.14, Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sat Oct 12 00:02:19 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: I got this error when executing `sox -V6 -n -t coreaudio junkname`: 
sox.exe FAIL formats: no handler for given file type `coreaudio'

Comment: `system_profiler SPAudioDataType` will list all audio devices on macOS